# Probability of forming an incorrect number when probability of an incorrect digit appearing is given.

Tags: probability

**Question:** A Binary number is made up of 8 digits. Suppose that he probability of an incorrect digit appearing is p and that the errors in different digits are independent of each other. Then find the probability of forming an incorrect number.

Why the answer isn't $p^8$? Text book states that the answer is $1-(1-p)^8$.

Comment: An incorrect number is formed if “at least one” of the digits is incorrect. In your way of counting, you are only looking at the case when ALL digits are incorrect.

Comment: @AnuragA Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p^8$ would be the probability of all the digits being incorrect.

In this case, we want to know the probability that 1 or more digits are incorrect.

So, the first thing to work out is what is the probability that none of the digits is incorrect.

- Each digit has a probability of $(1-p)$ of being correct.
- So all the digits will be correct with probability $(1-p)^8$.
- So you are looking for the probability that this will not occur, which has a probability of $1-(1-p)^8$.